# How to trace the code of kubernetes scheduler?

Tags: go, kubernetes, backend

I want to developed a custom kubernetes scheduler **plugin**. To have an initial idea for implemention, I checked another plugin like *node affinity* from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/scheduler/framework/plugins/nodeaffinity/node_affinity.go#L143-L168),
but checking code alone is not enough.
My main question is that, is there any approach for **tracing** the code to better undrestand the input and output of each method or function?
One idea came to my mind is forcing the source code to print the output like:

```
fmt.print(s.requiredNodeSelectorAndAffinity.Match(node))
```

But after recompiling scheduler, I am not sure if the output will be printed.